# How do you override web.xml in an Alfresco Share amp?

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I want to remove some of the configuration from the Alfresco Share `web.xml`. That file lives at `$TOMCAT_HOME/webapps/share/WEB-INF/web.xml` so I added the customized file to `$AMP_FOLDER/_share/config/META-INF/WEB-INF/web.xml`. The `WEB-INF` folder lives at the same level as other customizations - `compentents` and `css` - which get mapped to the `share.war` correctly. The `web.xml` file appears to just get ignored though (`find $TOMCAT_HOME/webapps/share -name web.xml` only finds the old version of the file).

How do I tell the amp file where to put the `web.xml` file?

All the documentation I have found says to not override the `web.xml` file, but I need to remove some of the filters that are being applied.

Comment: Can you not specify a `file-mapping.properties` to control where it ends up? (See [this](https://wiki.alfresco.com/wiki/AMP_Files#Customising_the_structure_of_an_AMP_file) for how to create one)

Comment: @Gagravarr I have `/WEB-INF=/WEB-INF` in my `file-mappiong.properties` but it doesn't seem to have any effect. I tried moving `WEB-INF` to the root of the `.amp` file as well and that didn't work either.

Comment: Are you using a recent enough copy of the MMT jar? (4.2.d version would be a good start)

Comment: I'm using version 0.96 of the alfresco-mmt.jar file. This is the version that comes with 4.1.5 (the version I'm trying to customize).

Comment: You might want to upgrade, as there have been quite a few fixes to the MMT during the 4.2.x development. You're fine to use a newer MMT jar with an older Alfresco instance, the format is common

Comment: TahirMalik's answer solved my issue, but I will definitely look into using the new version of MMT as working with AMPs has been a fairly constant source of pain when working with Alfresco.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use -force parameter when running the apply amps and don't put your web.xml in WEB-INF because mmt ignores that.

Use for example in the file-mapping.properties:

```
/web/WEB-INF=/WEB-INF
```

and

```
java -jar alfresco-mmt.jar install <AMPFileLocation> <WARFileLocation> -force
```

Comment: Works great when I put it under the web folder. Thanks!