# Where to place custom web.xml in Alfresco SDK 3.1

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-enterprise, alfresco-maven

I need to customize the web.xml and have it inside my custom jar. I have tried placing the web.xml in path "/project/src/main/resources/META-INF/resources/WEB-INF/web.xml". But after deploying the jar, changes are not reflected.

Sample changes: I tried changing the session timeout in the custom web.xml.

Alfresco version 5.2.5
sdk : 3.1

I doubt that am placing the xml in wrong path. Can someone please help me figure out what am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!!!!!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18729733/how-do-you-override-web-xml-in-an-alfresco-share-amp